# How to select mysql results?

Tags: php, mysql

**invoice**

```
+----+-----+---------+-------+
| Sr | BRN |  Name   |  Amnt |
+----+-----+---------+-------+
| 1  | 1   | John    |  10   |
| 2  | 1   | John    |   4   |
| 3  | 2   | Belly   |   4   |
| 4  | 3   | John    |  14   |
| 5  | 4   | John    |   5   |
| 6  | 4   | John    |  14   |
+----+-----+---------+-------+
```

I want to select all rows except the duplicate BRN. (If there are two/more ge in BRN then it should only select one)

I tried:

```
SELECT *(DISTINCT BRN) FROM invoice
```

Expected result:

```
+-----+---------+-------+
| BRN |  Name   |  Amnt |
+-----+---------+-------+
| 1   | John    |  10   |
| 2   | Belly   |   4   |
| 3   | John    |  14   |
| 4   | John    |   5   |
+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Only select one, but which one.. .the first, last, highest amount?  What is the basis of the ONE record you want.  What happens if you have multiple BRN values AND multiple secondary ARN records.  Do you want distinct per combination of BRN + ARN ?  You also don't have any date field indicated in your data.  So I would guess you want most recent date entry?

Comment: @DRapp `ARN` will be always same for same `BRN`. Selection can be of any.(No problem if it will take default row as first). I have skipped the date column here as it will not create any problems. Also, I have added some more rows to the database.

Comment: Are you wanting the latest occurrences of distinct BRN?

Comment: I didn't get you @TimMorton . Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47586711/how-to-select-mysql-results#comment82131416_47586711) will solve your doubt.

Comment: Clear as mud.  I don't know what a BRN, ARN, Amnt, ge, gw, gg, gq, etc is, so I have no context to give any clues as to what you are expecting.   What we really need is a subset of the data and the expected results.  Otherwise, we're going to waste our time scratching our heads trying to divine what you are asking.

Comment: If your expected results are simply [`ge`, `gw`, `gg`, `gq`], then the answer is quite simple. But if you are wanting entire rows instead of just the distinct BRNs, then that's another matter entirely, as DRapp was leading you to.

Comment: @TimMorton Hope **Edition** will help you more...

Comment: Indeed, that is much better.  In the future, though, please add edits below your initial question, as you have made all previous comments meaningless by completely changing the data.  On a good note, you're more likely to get the answer you're looking for now.

Comment: It should be mentioned, though, that the values in the `Amnt` column are pretty much meaningless.  Plus, having that column really complicates making the query.  If you don't need it, it would be much easier.

Comment: @TimMorton For this query the `amnt` is useless but for other uses it is very important!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following table:

```
+----+-----+---------+-------+
| Sr | BRN |  Name   |  Amnt |
+----+-----+---------+-------+
| 1  | 1   | John    |  10   |
| 2  | 1   | John    |   4   |
| 3  | 2   | Belly   |   4   |
| 4  | 3   | John    |  14   |
| 5  | 4   | John    |   5   |
| 6  | 4   | John    |  14   |
+----+-----+---------+-------+
```

with the expected results:

```
+-----+---------+-------+
| BRN |  Name   |  Amnt |
+-----+---------+-------+
| 1   | John    |  10   |
| 2   | Belly   |   4   |
| 3   | John    |  14   |
| 4   | John    |   5   |
+-----+---------+-------+
```

The difficult part is getting the amount, because it is arbitrary, not to mention that the values in `Amnt` are pretty much worthless in this result.

If you want distinct BRN, the query would be `SELECT DISTINCT BRN FROM invoice`

You might even get away with `SELECT DISTINCT BRN, Name FROM invoice`

An intermediate step would be `SELECT BRN,Name FROM invoice GROUP BY BRN, Name`

But if you try to include `Amnt` in the equation, then the query will fail because there's no way for the database to determine which Amnt to show.

So, you could try this kludge:

```
SELECT a.BRN, a.Name, b.Amnt FROM invoice AS a LEFT JOIN invoice AS b ON a.BRN=b.BRN
```

No guarantees on which Amnt it will pick up, though.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE Date >= :fdate GROUP BY BRN

Comment: I am getting `Fatal Error SQLSTATE[42000]` while executing your code.

Comment: Use GROUP BY BRN in Your Query

Comment: Columns in select must match columns in group by.  If you try to get `Amnt`, as in this query, it will fail.

Comment: SELECT * FROM invoice GROUP BY Amnt

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

See Here Use GROUP BY in Query with your Conditions